# Can sizeof(int) = 1 on either 32 or 64 bit platforms?

Tags: c++

In the section `N3797::3.9.1/2 [basic.fundamental]` there is:

> There are five standard signed integer types : “`signed char`”, “`short`
>   `int`”, “`int`”, “`long int`”, and “`long long int`”. In this list, each type
>   provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.

The standard explicitly defines size of `char, unsigned char, signed char` is 1. And that the size of plain `int`s depends on `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` as far as I understand not-standartized. So is it possible for implementation to define `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` such that `sizeof(int) = 1;`?

Comment: I'm sure it CAN, somehow, but I doubt that would be useful or used. I could be wrong.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546510/declaring-fixed-size-integer-typedef-in-standard-c

Comment: [`1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Comment: There are systems with 32-bit `char`s.

Comment: @T.C. and 36-bit `char`s, though I don't think those platforums support C++ or `long long`

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner: Can, and does. There are plenty of processors (DSPs in particular) whose smallest addressable unit is 32 bits (or 16,24,64,...), on which `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int) == 1`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit

Comment: @T.C. But sizeof(char) equals to 1. It's defined by the Standard.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Indeed it is. But it doesn't have to be 8 bits.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv `CHAR_BIT` isn't.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv "char" == "byte" != "octet".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as long as a byte has at least 16 bits, since that's the minimum size of `int`.

This is common on DSP architectures, which typically only allow access to, for example, 32-bit words of memory, and no smaller units.

Comment: That's on DSP sizeof(signed char) = sizeof(short) = sizeof(int) and there are consumed 32 bits amount of storage. Right?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: On a 32-bit architecture, with no addressable units smaller than 32 bits, yes.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. It is entirely possible for `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long` to all have the same 64-bit representation, which will have size 1.

The only effect this has on the standard library is to [remove some typedefs from `stdint.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) - specifically, `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`, `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`. Note that `uint8_least_t` and `uint8_fast_t`, etc., will still be provided.

Edit: add @user657267's link: [1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), which also includes the specific bit size requirements (though note that only the value ranges are normative)

The following value ranges must be supported:

- `signed char`: -(2<sup>7</sup>-1) to 2<sup>7</sup>-1
- `unsigned char`: 0 to 2<sup>8</sup>-1
- `signed short`: -(2<sup>15</sup>-1) to 2<sup>15</sup>-1
- `unsigned short`: 0 to 2<sup>16</sup>-1
- `signed int`: -(2<sup>15</sup>-1) to 2<sup>15</sup>-1
- `unsigned int`: 0 to 2<sup>16</sup>-1
- `signed long`: -(2<sup>31</sup>-1) to 2<sup>31</sup>-1
- `unsigned long`: 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1
- `signed long long`: -(2<sup>63</sup>-1) to 2<sup>63</sup>-1
- `unsigned long long`: 0 to 2<sup>64</sup>-1

Edit: inlined more information from the links